# WedSocket data format of JupyterLab 4

Tags: websocket, binary, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am currently developing an integration system between Moodle and JupyterHub. One of the functions of the system is to hook jupyter's WebSocket communication and display the learning progress in Moodle.

https://gitlab.nsl.tuis.ac.jp/iseki/lticontainerspawner/-/wikis/Moodle-+-JupyterHub
https://gitlab.nsl.tuis.ac.jp/iseki/mod_lticontainer/-/wikis/mod_lticontainer

However, starting with v4.0 of JupyterLab, WebSocket communications are prefixed with binary data starting with 0x06 0x00.

ex.)

```
06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 -+  
38 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |
3d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |
06 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |-- here format?
e2 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |
e4 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |
ff 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 -+
69 6f 70 75 62 7b 22 6d
73 67 5f 69 64 22 3a 20
22 30 33 34 64 65 34 61
62 2d 35 32 63 37 33 32
```

If anyone knows where I can find some information about the format of this data, please let me know.

I have searched around the following URL, but have not found any information on binary data

https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/messaging.html

I need to know the format of the binary communication data added in JupyterLab 4.

Best Regards,